# Maven repository with a JAR and native dll's

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I am writing a maven plugin to control another java program (jar). This jar needs two dlls in the same directory. I would like to install the jar and this two dlls as a maven repo into local .m2 dir or a maven repository server.

I have used following command to create the local repo for the jar within my project:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5:install-file -Dfile=protector.jar -DgroupId=com.protect -DartifactId=protector -Dversion=10.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=lib
```

But now i do not know how i can get the dlls in the same dir like the jar file. If i use the above command then maven creates new folder for each dll and rename it.

Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: Are those dll's needed during build time or runtime ?

Comment: There are needed during runtime

Comment: So you should produce a correct distribution package like zip where the user simply can extract that and start it...So you can install files as an classifier artifact. This can be achieved by using the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/)...